# Approaches for rendering Java Swing applications straight to a video

Tags: java, video-encoding

I want to write an application a 2D animation sequence and then render that to a video.  What approaches and software do you use to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Werner Randelhofer's [AVIDemo](http://randelshofer.ch/software.html) which is a pure Java solution to create simple AVI movies. Definitely not as fast as a native approach like Xuggle, but very easy to setup and use. Werner also has a new Monte Media Library which seems to supersede the AVIDemo, but I haven't yet worked with it, so I cannot say how easy it is to use.

**Update 8/2017**

[JCodec](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec) provides encoders for several movie formats, including H.264 / MP4. It can take a series of BufferedImages (e.g. automated screenshots taken with Java) and turn them into a video file.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/). This [tutorial](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Encoding_Video_from_a_sequence_of_Images) should help you. Below a simple example - you can easily build upon it.

“Real time” example of creating a video stream from individual frames:

```
IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("C:/movie.mp4");
// We tell it we're going to add one video stream, with id 0,
// at position 0, and that it will have a fixed frame rate of
// FRAME_RATE.
writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, IRational.make(FRAME_RATE), width, height);
try {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(true) {
        final BufferedImage screen = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        // Draw the frame
        // encode the image to stream #0
        writer.encodeVideo(0, screen, System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(1000/FRAME_RATE);
    }
} catch (RuntimeException x) {
    // Problem
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```